# Center a drawable in a Button with background and no text

Tags: android, button

I have a few buttons in my Android app. They each look kinda like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/an_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/a_background"
    android:layout_width="size_dp"
    android:layout_height="size_dp">
</Button>
```

Granted, I'm new to Android dev, but I can't figure out how to center the drawable in my button. I've tried the different drawableLocations, margins and padding for the button and its container, as well as drawablePadding, but I can't seem to get it done. Is there a way to center the drawable without abandoning Button for another View?

Comment: Are you using an image as a background drawable, if yes, try using an imageView and pass it as a src it will automatically fit the button. I found a link saying at times your code centers it and it is visible on a real device, eclipse misses that. Give this a try as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711468/center-a-drawable-in-a-button-with-background-and-no-text

Comment: Yes, the background image is a somewhat large "empty button", and it is used in many other places in the application. For that reason, I have set hard dp width and height values for the Button (no wrap_content). I'm also not using the Graphical Visualizer -- just a test device, to make sure all my changes reflect the way it actually looks. Also, did you mean to link to this question? lol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way to center the `drawable` without abandoning `Button`

So you can have both (background & drawable) by using `ImageView` as below: (So No need to use Button)

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/an_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/a_background" />
```

For `OnClick` of `ImageView`:

```
findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it abandons the clickable functionality, which I'm not too eager to reimplement. However, this may be the way to go if I can't figure out another solution.

Comment: ImageView provide the same clickable functionality as Button.

Comment: While it wasn't as easy as changing a property in the Button view, this did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

The easiest solution is to use [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) widget:

```
<ImageButton
    (...)
    android:background="@drawable/a_background"
    android:src="@drawable/an_icon"
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/an_icon"
        android:background="@drawable/a_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="151dp">
    </Button>
```

Comment: The alignment and margin properties will just move the button in relation to its container, when I need to reposition the content of the button.