# how to give margin to svg icon in android?

Tags: android, icons, margin

I am a new beginner in android development and try to give margin **SVG google icon** from the **top** inside the button on the search bar.I know its quick fix but I already try margin properties not affected!

**XML**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:background="#3bbdfa"/>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="13"
    android:textColor="#CCC"
    android:hint="Search..."
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />
```

**output**

[see search-bar here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKF0n.png)

can anyone have the solution? any help is appreciated.

Comment: #Navjot Try to give drawablepadding

Comment: thanks for comment sir its not working nothing changed!

Comment: Use ImageView or ImageButton better for doing that kind of work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ImageView instead a Button as explained in this answer,
[Center a drawable in a Button with background and no text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711468/center-a-drawable-in-a-button-with-background-and-no-text)